# Computer doesn't exist sleep mode on Ubuntu 20.04, solving it removes wifi setting

Tags: wireless, kernel, suspend

I have a new laptop (HP Pavilion 15-eh1035nf with AMD Ryzen 7 and AMD Radeon graphics) on which I have installed Ubuntu on a dual boot with Windows.

On Windows, everything works fine. But on Ubuntu (20.04 with kernel 5.13), when the computer goes to sleep mode (either with time or by closing the laptop), it is impossible to get it to wake up and i eventually have to hard reboot it.

Trough my research, I found several solutions (mostly for NVIDIA drivers, so not for me) and one that said that the problem came from the kernel itself.
So I installed mainline and updated the kernel to several versions (5.14.0, 5.14.10, 5.15.0, ...) and even though I had to deactivate secure boot to make them work because they were unsigned, it solved my problem : I could get out of sleep mode !

But now I face another issue : On these upgraded versions, I have no WiFi settings, which is really annoying. (I still have Bluetooth though)
*Note that my wireless card is Realtek RTL8852AE, I don't know if that can help*

So I have the choice between hard-rebooting my computer every time it goes to sleep, or get a working sleep mode but no internet connexion...

I'm really out of Ideas and hope someome here can help figuring out which one is the easiest to fix ^^

**TL; DR :** Laptop doesn't wake up from sleep mode, upgrading the kernel fixes it but then there is no wifi, I can't solve it, help.

Comment: the driver for your wireless card is only included in the mainline kernel as of 5.16. I guess Ubuntu added it to their versions of the kernel, but the mainline versions won't have it. Maybe try 5.16 to see if your wifi works on that version?

Comment: 20.04 is not designed to work with 5.15 but, if you don't mind trialing an early release of 22.04, you might consider using the next LTS, which does ship with the 5.15 kernel. We cannot yet ask for support with 22.04 on AskUbuntu, but it has proven to be pretty solid with the daily builds. This may give you the functionality that you need 

Comment: @Esther I already tried with 15.16, it doesn't work but like matigo said, this version is not supposed to work with my Ubuntu version. But I get now why this doesnt work, thank you !
Is there then any way I can add the pilot to Ubuntu booting with let's say 5.14 kernel ?

Comment: @SimonB yes, you can compile and install the driver yourself. [This github page](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89) has code and complete instructions on how to install the driver you need.

Comment: **Update :** I tried it with 5.16 (previously tried it with 5.15 my bad) and it seems to work perfectly ?
I have Wifi and the sleep mode is working...
I will add a solution for those who are looking to solve this issue (because there is no simple solution to that problem ^^)

Thank you ! :D

Comment: "Hibernation" needs as much swap as you have RAM. Use the terminal command `free` to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **The Issue :**

**Equipement :** HP Pavilion 15-eh1035nf with AMD Ryzen 7, AMD Radeon graphics, and Realtek RTL8852AE wireless card.

From what I get, the 5.13 version of Ubuntu Kernel does not support correctly the drivers of my equipement, causing the computer to not recieve any inputs after entering sleep mode.
(https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/suhbo1/laptop_doesnt_wake_up_from_sleepsuspend/)

### **Solution :**

Upgrading the kernel to 5.14 worked for the sleep mode issue (this version aparently added fixes for Ryzen CPUs), but the drivers for the wireless card are only included after 5.16 kernel. And as @matigo said :

> 20.04 is not designed to work with 5.15

In my case, upgrading the kernel to 5.16 worked fine for me, the computer can get out of sleep mode and I have wifi. (Though as soon as there is a new stable version of Ubuntu with 5.16 or above kernel I will make sure to upgrade my system)

Another solution, suggested by @Esther (that I did not test) is to upgrade to 5.14 kernel and manually install the wireless card driver

### **How to do it ?**

To install a new version of the kernel, I installed Mainline : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/mainline

Then I had to deactivate the secure boot on my computer because the kernels here are not signed, and installed the 5.16.0 kernel

The nice part about this is that if there is a problem with the kernel I installed (like the absence of wifi settings), I still can boot on the older kernels installed with GRUB (via `Advanced options for ubuntu`)

---

*Thank you for the help, I hope this post can help other who face the same issue !*